# Why the compiler doesnot complain about the toFixed() used in below code

Tags: typescript

```
function car (car: {
    make: string,
    model: string,
    year: number,
    chargeVoltage?: number
}){
    console.log(`${car.model} was made by ${car.make} in year ${car.year} ${car.chargeVoltage.toFixed(2)}`)
}

car({
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Fortuner',
    year: 1997
})
```

Above is the code that i have written in Vs code.

The problem faced is that my compiler is not complaining on using `toFixed()` method on `chargeVoltage`.
Actually it need to give type error as the `chargeVolage` is optional property.

## Package.json

```
{
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Repo focussed on learning typescript",
  "main": "src",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "tsc --watch --preserveWatchOutput"
  },
  "author": "Atul Singh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2017", // which level of js support to target
        "outDir": "dist",    // where to put the ts file
       
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

I tried to calling function `car` as below:

```
car({
    make: 'Ford',
    model: 'Fortuner',
    year: 1997
})
```

- Upon running the file, i am actually getting the type error on run-time, which i believe should be caught on compile time, as it the feature of typescript

Comment: Try enabling strict mode by adding `"strict": true` to compiler options in tsconfig

Comment: With strict, I get `TS18048: 'car.chargeVoltage' is possibly 'undefined'.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks).

When strictNullChecks is true, null and undefined have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

There is a complete family of strict checks and I think you would want to enable all of them using [`"strict": true`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) in your tsconfig.json. And then you can individually switch one off like - `"strictPropertyInitialization" : false`